# "DateWithFormat" works on terminal but not on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have some code that does operations with dates. To see if it would work, I wrote a really simple program for the OSX console. It works fine! However, I wanted to start making an app so I used the same code in a function in a view-based application. However, I keep getting an error saying: "No known class method dateWithFormat."
Any help would be appreciated!

```
-(id)calc:(int)m with:(int)d andWith:(int)y {


 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSDate *date1 =[formatter setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i-%i 00:00:00 +0000",m,d,y]];
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    int numberOfDays = secondsBetween/86400;
 }
```

Comment: I can't believe that code works anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: In your snippet you do not use `+dateWithFormat: (NSDate)`, but `+dateWithString: (NSDate)`. Typo? Please, re-check this. `+dateWithFormat: (NSDate)` does not exist on Mac OS and iOS.

Second: `-dateWithString: (NSDate)` is not available on iOS. It is a convenient method. Use a [date formatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to transform a string to a date. (And this is the better way on Mac OS, too.)

Third, updated to your comment:
Your code should not compile:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"%i-%i-%i 00:00:00 +0000",1,2,3];

Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 4
```

Probably you want to do something like that:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i-%i 00:00:00 +0000",1,2,3]];
```

If you want to create a date with specific values on components of the date, have a look at [NSDatComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. Actually, my title has a typo, my code is correct. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a date formatter, as I've updated in my initial question. However I am getting the error: "Initializing 'NSDate*_strong' with an expression of incompatible type'void'." Any clue to what this could entail? The code for dateformatter looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: Rereading your code, date components seems to be the better approach. Look at the end of my answer. Anyway: Without having a look to your source code, I cannot say, what went wrong.